# Better way to fill my firebase with pre-defined values, if is the first time the user log-ins

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am building an app, that have a lot of matches to a user make bets.

Its for the World Cup. I have a big json with all data, and want to upload it to firebase the first time the user logs in. If its not the first time, its just fetch the data previosly saved at firebase.

What is the better way to make this? Like:

```
if(firstTimeUsersLogs){
    loadDefaultValuesFromJson();

}else{
  fetchDataFromFirebase()   

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Firebase Authentication Trigger as documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events.

You could set up a trigger that runs once on the Firebase servers just after a user is created; that trigger can update data in the database for the user, which could include defaulting certain values. Your React app would then be able to read that data when it needs it.

Or you could fetch the data from your firebase ref in both cases, if the returned data is `null` you know that no data exist in this ref then you can call your `loadDefaultValuesFromJson();` but if the returned data is not `null` you can work with it

Or You can use the Realtime Database to store the first time login status of a given user, identified by their uid provided by Auth. You can check this in your auth listener that gets triggered when authentication happens successfully and based on this you can call the desired function